# How to prove this nice $10$th power identity for $x_1^6+x_2^6+x_3^6 =y_1^6+y_2^6+y_3^6$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

[*Ramanujan's 6-10-8 Identity*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ramanujan6-10-8Identity.html) turns out to [depend](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382907/generalizing-ramanujans-6-10-8-identity) on a special case of,
$$u_1^k+u_2^k+u_3^k =v_1^k+v_2^k+v_3^k$$
simultaneously valid for $k=2,4$. I was investigating if the *next* system $k=2,6$,
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2 =y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2\\x_1^6+x_2^6+x_3^6 =y_1^6+y_2^6+y_3^6\tag1$$
would have something similar. I observed empirically that,
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^3\big(x_i^{10}-y_i^{10}\big)\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^3\big(x_i^{4}-y_i^{4}\big)\right)^2=20\prod_{i=1}^3\prod_{j=1}^3\big(x_i^2-y_j^2\big)\tag2$$
**Example:**
$$10^k+15^k+23^k = 3^k+19^k+22^k$$
yields,
$$\small \text{LHS}= \big(10^{10} + 15^{10} + 23^{10} - 3^{10} - 19^{10} - 22^{10}\big)\big(10^4 + 15^4 + 23^4 - 3^4 - 19^4 - 22^4\big)^2$$
$$\small \text{RHS}=20(10^2 - 3^2)(10^2 - 19^2)(10^2 - 22^2)(15^2 - 3^2)(15^2 - 19^2)(15^2 - 22^2)(23^2 - 3^2)(23^2 - 19^2)(23^2 - 22^2)$$
$$\small\text{LHS}=\text{RHS}=37739520^2\times3830610$$
I've also tested it with more general parametric solutions and it works just fine.

> **Q:** But how do we prove $(2)$ rigorously?

Comment: why so many squares ?

Comment: @mercio: I observed this while working with $x_1^k+x_2^k+x_3^k = y_1^k+y_2^k+y_3^k$ for $k=2,4$. I'm not sure if the version $k=1,3$ and signed $x_i, y_i$ will work, but fortunately $(1)$ has infinitely many solutions to play with.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III Is this question still of interest?

Comment: @OldPeter: Feel free to answer it still.  :)

Comment: @Tito Piezas III
I hate to ask, but is there and chance of a typo in your identity?
I’ve tried substituting some small solutions, but the RHS of (2) seems vastly too small.
Perhaps I’ve misunderstood the notation; I’ve take then RHS of (2) as the product of
20*(x_1^2-y1_^2)(x_1^2-y_2^2)(x_1^2-y3_^2)$(x_2^2-y_12^2)(x_2^2-y_2^2)(x_2^2-y_3^2)(x3_^2-y_1^2)(x_3^2-y_2^2)(x_3^2-y_3^2)

Comment: Sorry, I failed to make that show correctly.  20 times the product of nine factors of the form $x^2-y^2$

Comment: I don't understand why ask these questions? You do not need the answers. All the time repeat one and the same in a modified form.

Comment: @OldPeter: I re-tested it and it's ok. And I've edited the post to make it detailed. Pls compare your RHS and LHS with the post.

Comment: @Individ: I've seen your posts, individ. You really should address that question to yourself.

Comment: @Tito Piezas III Thank you so much for the numerical example, for my stupid, school boy error is now clear: I took the LHS sums as products! Sorry.

Comment: @OldPeter: Ok.  :)

Comment: @Tito Piezas III
I’ve looked at a good few solutions, including some also valid for $k=1$
I expect these are nothing new, but I have noticed the following:

$(x_1^2-y_1^2)+(x_2^2-y_2^2)+(x_3^2-y_3^2)=0$, 

$(x_1^2-y_3^2)+(x_2^2-y_1^2)+(x_3^2-y_2^2)=0$, 

$(x_1^2-y_2^2)+(x_2^2-y_3^2)+(x_3^2-y_1^2)=0$

Also, put

$A=(x_1-y_1)+(x_2-y_2)+(x_3-y_3)$, then 

$(x_1-y_3)+(x_2-y_1)+(x_3-y_2)=A$, and,

$(x_1-y_2)+(x_2-y_3)+(x_3-y_1)=A$

In addition, put

$B=(x_1+y_1)+(x_2+y_2)+(x_3+y_3)$, then 

$(x_1+y_3)+(x_2+y_1)+(x_3+y_2)=B$, and,

$(x_1+y_2)+(x_2+y_3)+(x_3+y_1)=B$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $$R_n=(a_1^n+a_2^n+a_3^n -b_1^n-b_2^n-b_3^n)/n$$
I found and proved that 
$$R_1S+R_3^3-2R_2R_3R_4+R_2^2R_5=\prod_{i=1}^3\prod_{j=1}^3\big(a_i-b_j\big)$$
where $S$ is a polynomial containing 9 items.

If $R_1=R_2=0$, then $$R_3^3=\prod_{i=1}^3\prod_{j=1}^3\big(a_i-b_j\big)$$
Example: $2^n+13^n+21^n=6^n+7^n+23^n$, $(n=1,2)$

If $R_1=R_3=0$, then $$R_2^2R_5=\prod_{i=1}^3\prod_{j=1}^3\big(a_i-b_j\big)$$
Example: $2^n+10^n+12^n=3^n+8^n+13^n$, $(n=1,3)$

If $R_1=R_4=0$, then $$R_3^3+R_2^2R_5=\prod_{i=1}^3\prod_{j=1}^3\big(a_i-b_j\big)$$
Example: $3^n+25^n+38^n=7^n+20^n+39^n$, $(n=1,4)$

If $R_1=R_5=0$, then $$R_3^3-2R_2R_3R_4=\prod_{i=1}^3\prod_{j=1}^3\big(a_i-b_j\big)$$
Example: $3^n+54^n+62^n=24^n+28^n+67^n$, $(n=1,5)$

Let $a_i=x_i^2,b_i=y_i^2$, $(i=1,2,3)$, the system $(1)$ satisfies $R_1=R_3=0$, then we can prove equation $(2)$.

For more identities of the similar form, please refer to my website on [Algebraic Identities](http://eslpower.org/Identity.htm)

For more examples of numerical solutions, please refer to my website on [Equal Sums of Like Powers](http://eslpower.org/eslp.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove equation $(2).$ Using equation $(1)$ with $k=2$ solve the quadratic for say $y_3$. Substitute this value of $y_3$ into  LHS-RHS  of equation $(1)$ with $k=6$ to get a homogeneous $6$th degree polynomial in the $5$ other variables. Substitute the value of $y_3$ into LHS-RHS of equation $(2)$ and verify that the result is a homogeneous $18$th degree polynomial divisible by the homogeneous $6$th degree polynomial.